# Nexus 5 site - scroll slider inside device - how to do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slider, parallax

I want to make the same effect as is on Nexus 5 site ( http://www.google.com/nexus/5/ ) - this with staying Nexus and changeable screens inside of it while I am scrolling (it's 4th section).

My case is that I have same section on my site, but with an iPad in the center and text content on both sides and I want to change just images inside the iPad while I will be scrolling.

Any ideas, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at this:
**http://jsfiddle.net/sTH5w/47/show/**

basically control the slider via 'scroll' event and the position - `scrollTop()`
for example:

```
if(/* some condition with $(document).scrollTop() */) {
    if($('#img2').css("margin-top") == "295px") { // if the image is down
        $('#img2').animate({"margin-top": "0px"}, 300); // slide the image up
    }
}
```

see full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sTH5w/47/

**NOTE:** in my example, ALL the content after the slider must be in `<div id="after-slider">` to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

**To do the 4th section**
First what you want to do is make a PNG of an IPad with a transparent center. This can be done by googling "IPad" and finding an image that you like, then go into your favorite image editing program and mask and delete out the center part of the IPad(Where the content would go).

The next thing you have to do is center the image of an IPad on a webpage. This can be done by puting the picture in a `<img>` tag like so
`<img src="pathToIpadPicture" id="mainPic">`
then add some css

```
#mainPic {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: calc(50% - heightOfYourPictureHere);
}
```

That should center the picture vertically and horizontally in your page.

Now you want to add in the interactive scroll part. This is why we made a IPad with a IPad with a transparent center. Now you have make some content. Make this content as big as the center of your IPad. Than add these pictures of content to your web page and center them the same way we did for the IPad picture. Make sure to hide them with
`display: none`
until they are needed. Then when the user scrolls at certain points animate the content pictures up. A good library for animating with Jquery is [JS Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). With the proper animation it should look just like the Nexus 5 page. If you want little text bubbles saying what the content is (like "HDR") just do the same thing but put them above the IPad frame(Layer wise) and animate them up the same way.